# Are the transactions displayed on "BitListen" really accurate?

Tags: exchanges, trading, trade, finance

Over the years, whenever there's unusual Bitcoin activity, I look at: https://www.bitlisten.com/

But can these transactions really be accurate? I just saw numerous 100+ BTC ones, and just now a gigantic one of 946.92 BTC (!!).

According to my exchange rate calculator, that is:

```
BTC 946.92 = $22,731,761.52 USD
```

Almost twenty-three million US dollars... at once?

I realize that a lot of money is being traded right now, but even if somebody has that many Bitcoin to trade, would they really do it all in one go? Isn't that very risk? Wouldn't you split it up into at least hundreds of different transactions?

I don't understand what kind of person or entity would make a single transaction of such a huge sum. Is this really accurate or faked somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's real. If you don't believe it you can simply look at a block explorer and view many other transactions of similar sizes.